# What's up with mongoose date/timestamps?

Tags: date, mongoose, timestamp

I've a problem. I've been trying 2 different approaches to get correct date after an item is added to the collection.

```
1. new Date()
2. Date.now()
```

Both examples has the same issue. Only first added document has correct date. The next one has exactly the same date. Why the date is not changing?

Here's my collection:

```
const commentSchema = new Schema({
    author: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'user'
  },
  addDate: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now()
  },
  content: String,
  answers: [commentReplies],
  articleID: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'article'
  }
});
```

My insertion code:

```
app.post('/api/comments/addComment', async (req, res) => {
const author = req.body.author,
      content = req.body.content,
      articleID = req.body.articleID;

const comment = await new Comment({
  author, content, articleID
}).save().catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
})
res.send();
```

})

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: post updated with code

Comment: Please add the relevant code for the insertion.

Comment: updated the post

Answer (score 0):

Because doing that way mongoose use the date at the time the schema is created: it execute the `Date.now()` function and use the value as the default for every document.

Probably the better way to do it is to use a save hook and set the date programmatically in the hook.

Comment: what do you mean exactly? Something like Schema.pre('save'...) or what..?

Comment: ok.. I've just added new variable that stores new Date() to the post route. Thanks.